# how to run multiple spec files in parallel on the same chrome browser in protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I would like to run my specs across multiple instances of the same browser to cut down on time

```
   multiCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    maxInstances: 5,
    shardTestFiles: true,        
},
```

yet i still keep getting all files run one after another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multiCapabilities` should be an Array, you define it into an object.

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    maxInstances: 5,
    shardTestFiles: true,        
}],
```

Alternative to use single capabilities, which expect an object.

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    maxInstances: 5,
    shardTestFiles: true,        
},
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `maxSessions`(declared outside of capabilities) will override `maxInstances` so make sure that you have it set appropriately.